Managing Angular Code with Dynamic Template Requirements
We have a scenario where our Angular application consists of common components, services, pipes, etc., alongside dynamically loaded templates from a database for various customized applications. Due to limitations, dynamic template loading isn't feasible.
Requirement:

We have Angular code for common components, services, and pipes.
Different applications store their templates in a database.
Dynamic loading of templates from the database isn't an option.

Challenge:
How can we effectively manage and integrate these dynamically required templates with our existing Angular application structure?
Question:
What strategies or best practices should we consider to integrate and manage dynamically required templates from a database within our Angular application architecture?
Current Approach:

We have explored options for dynamic loading but found them impractical.
Considering pre-compilation of templates, but unsure about the best practice.


A lot of website builders work like having confirmed JSON schema where you will define the UI of your page, then the client side will get that JSON from the server, run logic to render all the components (mostly it's done recursively) and your dynamic UI is ready coming from the database.

This is not how Angular is supposed to work : consider using another library/framework/language ?

I think a lot depends upon the content of the DB stored templates: are they Angular components? Are they simple key/value replacements? Depending upon the requirement, you could preprocess the HTML as a string and then use Angular's sanitizer to fill in InnerHtml.
